# Separating angular frontend for views from Yii backend Controller and Model

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, yii

I'm trying to implement an angular frontend and a yii backend such that angular will handle all the routing and views whereas yii will just handle the controllers/model and database connection. Angular can send ajax requests for data which will be handled by the [RESTfullYii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/) extension. I've already implemented this through inserting angular code in the yii view files.

What I want though is both of them to be completely separate interacting only through the REST extension.

I'm trying to copy the structure in this app where the frontend is in a separate folder from yii's protected folder, but I don't know how to set the routing such that it will automatically render the index.html file from the angular-yii folder.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/497/angularjs-frontend-connecting-it-with-a-yii-backend-rest-api-gallery-manager-demo-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

Apparently just had to point the url to my angular files then then set the .htaccess rewrite engine on to make sure yii does not handle it.